# ensure that current user can make changes only to his data django/python

Tags: python, django

I want that only current user can make changes only to his data in django

for example activate/desactivate content tha he created..

this my view function for activating a product :

```
def Activer(request, produit_id):
   produit = Produit.objects.get(pk=produit_id)
   produit.etat = "active"
   produit.save()
   return JsonResponse({'success':True})
```

and this is my code in produit.html :

```
{% if produit.etat == "active" %}
```

however this is accessible for all user ..

Comment: Could you add your models and please elaborate the question further explaining what have you done so far as well as what error are you getting?

Comment: show your models ad full template

Comment: Models for etat :    

` etat = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=etat_choix, default="desactive" )`

Comment: Tell us about Produit model?

Comment: Please add your models in your question. Don't post it in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if Produit is created by current user else tell the user that Produit is not allowed to be edited.

```
def Activer(request, produit_id):
   produit = Produit.objects.get(pk=produit_id)
   if produit.user.id == request.user.id: ## check if this produit is created current user.
       produit.etat = "active"
       produit.save()
       return JsonResponse({'success':True})
   else: # else response the user that not allowed to edit the Produit.
       return JsonResponse({'error':'You are not allowed to edit this product.'})
```

Comment: it always returns 

`'error':'You are not allowed to edit this product.'`

while i just added the product for current user...

Comment: i think there's a problem with `filter` attribute 
   `produit = Produit.objects.filter(pk=produit_id)`
it returns :`'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'
`
when i change it to `get` it worked but always returns `'error':'You are not allowed to edit this product.'`

Comment: See, there should be way to know, Produit is related user. Tell me How are you deciding if Produit can be edited by user?

Answer (score 1):

```
@login_required    
def Activer(request, produit_id):
    try:
        produit = Produit.objects.get(pk=produit_id)

        if produit.user == request.user: ## check if this produit is created by current user.
            produit.etat = "active"
            produit.save()

            return JsonResponse({'success':True})

        else: # else response the user that not allowed to edit the Produit.

           return JsonResponse({'error':'You are not allowed to edit this produit.'})

    except Produit.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error' : 'object dose not exist'})
```

If you want to have the ***request.user*** in your ***request*** object as an authenticated user not anonymous, you should call your view in logged in state.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to simply use `update()` rather than doing a select, update, save:

```
@login_required
def Activer(request, produit_id):
    count = Produit.objects.filter(pk=produit_id, user=request.user).update(etat='active')
    return JsonResponse({'success': count == 1}
```

This has the advantage of avoiding a potential race condition that might occur in between loading the object from the database and subsequently saving it back.